# Indexing variable created by awk in bash

Tags: bash, indexing, awk, split

I'm having some trouble indexing a variable (consisting of 1 line with 4 values) derived from a text file with awk.

In particular, I have a text-file containing all input information for a loop. Every row contains 4 specific input values, and every iteration makes use of a different row of the input file.

Input file looks like this:

```
/home/hannelore/TVB-pipe_local/subjects/CON02T1/ 10012 100000 1001 --> used for iteration 1
/home/hannelore/TVB-pipe_local/subjects/CON02T1/ 10013 7200 1001 --> used for iteration 2
...
```

From this input text file, I identified the different columns (path, seed, count, target), and then I wanted to index these variables in each iteration of the loop. However, index 0 returns the entire variable and higher indices return without output. Using awk, cut, or IFS on this obtained variable, I wasn't able to split the variable. Can anyone help me with this?

Some code that I used:

```
seed=$(awk '{print $2}' $input_file)
```

--> extract column information from input file, this works

```
seedsplit=$(awk '{print $2}' $seed)

seedsplit=$(cut -f2 -d ' ' $seed)"
```

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,

Hannelore

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in the `seedsplit` assignments. The second argument to `awk` is a filename, but `$seed` contains all the values from field 2 of the input file.

Comment: Not enough information. What files are at those path locations? What do they contain and what are you trying to extract from them?

Comment: What variable are you trying to index? I don't see any arrays in your code.

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is make `seed` an array: `seed=($(awk '{print $2}' $input_file))`. Then you can use `${seed[0]}`, `${seed[1]}` and so on to index it.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar, using an extra pair of brackets made it work like I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to extract the values from the input file row by row.

```
while read a b c d; do echo "var1:" ${a}; done < file
```

will print

```
var1: /home/hannelore/TVB-pipe_local/subjects/CON02T1/
var1: /home/hannelore/TVB-pipe_local/subjects/CON02T1/
```

similarly you can access the other variables in b,c, and d.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array, then use array assignment notation:

```
seed=( $(awk '{print $2}' $input_file) )
```

Now you will have the words from each line of output from `awk` in a separate array element.

```
col1=( $(awk '{print $1}' $input_file) )
col3=( $(awk '{print $3}' $input_file) )
```

Now you have three arrays which can be indexed in parallel.

```
for i in $(seq 1 "${#col1[@]}"
do
    echo "${col1[$i]} in col1; ${seed[$i]} in col2; ${col3[$i]} in col3"
done
```